# joomla unwanted span tag after each enter

Tags: joomla, editor, html

When I'm trying to add text in new article in text editor after each enter the editor automatically make a span with default style 
what should i do to prevent this ?

```
<span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" ></span>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all which editor you are using ?

In Joomla go to your Editor configuration and Choose proper tag for `Enter` and `Shift+Enter`

for all modern editor this will available  eg: if you using `CKEditor`

Go to Admin->Components->CkEditor -> Advanced Settings.

[image]

Hope its helps..